# How to pass id (a variable) from one html page to another html?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I can't figure it out for a few days, please help. I have several html pages, I need to transfer `{{ region.id }}` from Test page to add_department page. I tried to use `{% block action_block %} action="/add_department/{{ region.id }}" {% endblock action_block %}`, but only `action="/add_department/` without `region.id` is passed, why is this happening and how to fix it?

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/all.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/main.css' %}">

    {% block title %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
    <aside>
        <h3>Menu</h3>
        <ul>
            <a href="{% url 'home' %}"><li>Main page</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'Test' %}"><li>Test page</li></a>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <main>
    {% block page %}
    {% endblock page %}
    </main>

{% include 'add_department.html' %}


    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/jquery-3.6.4.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/script.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<html>
<head>
    {% block title %}
     <title>Test page</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
{% block page %}
<div class="features">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center" role="tablist">
            {% for region in regions %}
                {% if region.id == 7 %}
                    {% for department in departments %}
                        {% if region.id == department.region_id_id %}
                            <button class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#region-{{ department.id }}" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="region-{{ department.id }}">{{ department.department_name }}</button>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    <a><button class="btn btn-success btn-add btn-padding-left btn-add-department" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#add_departmentModal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add department</button></a>
                <div>
                     {% block action_block %} action="/add_department/{{ region.id }}" {% endblock action_block %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </nav>
 
    ....
    
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

add_department.html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add_departmentModal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Add department</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <form {% block action_block %}{% endblock action_block %} method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" class="card p-3 border-dark mt-3">
                {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="modal-body">
                <label for="id_department_name">Department name: </label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <span class="btn border-secondary bg-light"></span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="department_name" maxlength="128" placeholder="Department name:" required>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="region_id" maxlength="128" placeholder="" value="{{ region.id }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-4" style="width: 100%;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mb-2"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add</button>
                    <a href="{% url 'Test' %}" class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-2 ms-2"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>&nbsp;Back</a>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-2 ms-2"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>&nbsp;Reset</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from mainapp.views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home', home_view, name='home'),
    path('Test', test_view, name='Test'),
    path('add_department/<int:pk>', add_department_view, name='add_department'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Region, Department, Site, Building, Room, Rack, Device
from .forms import *
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
from .forms import *
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


# Create your views here.
def home_view(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def login_view(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')


def test_view(request):
    return render(request, 'Test.html', {
        'regions': Region.objects.all(),
        'departments': Department.objects.all(),
    })
def add_department_view(request, pk):
    answer = '123'
    form = DepartmentForm(request.POST or None)
    data = {'form': form, 'answer': answer, 'region_id': pk}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.department_name = request.POST.get('department_name')
            form.region_id = pk
            model_instance = form.save()
            model_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/Test')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
    else:
        return render(request, 'add_department.html', data)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *


class DepartmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ['department_name', 'region_id']
        widgets = {
            'department_name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }
            ),
            'region_id': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Region(models.Model):
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, verbose_name='Region')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'region'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.region_name


class Department(models.Model):
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, verbose_name='Department')
    region_id = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'department'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.department_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

your code with hardcoded link:

```
 {% block action_block %} action="/add_department/{{ region.id }}" {% endblock action_block %}
```

new code:

```
 {% block action_block %} action="{% url 'add_department' region.pk %}" {% endblock action_block %}
```

Comment: an interesting solution, I didn’t think of it, I tried it, unfortunately it didn’t help, an empty string is passed to the form now :(